# how to refresh kendo combobox in angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

I want to refresh the kendo combobox in angular code. i am trying using jquery it's not working.

```
$("#customObject").data("kendoComboBox").refresh();
```

Comment: can you add more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add in view a new item in your datasource, for example :

```
$("#customObject").data("kendoComboBox").dataSource.add({ prop1: "foo", prop2: "bar" });
```

by this way you don't have to do `dataSource.read()`, it may take time sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you mean reload the data?
Try this;

```
$("#customObject").data("kendoComboBox").dataSource.read();
```

Comment: How is the combo box wired to its data source.  Need to see some more code here.